# Issue with iPhone5 and iPhone6 @2x images

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6, ios-icons

What is the official iOS naming convention for(@2X),

iPhone 6 :

667x375 points  1334x750 pixels     2x scale    1334x750 physical pixels    326 physical ppi    4.7"

iPhone 5 :

568x320 points  1136x640 pixels     2x scale    1136x640 physical pixels    326 physical ppi    4.0"

iPhone 4 :

480x320 points  960x640 pixels      2x scale    960x640 physical pixels     326 physical ppi    3.5"

so, that device recognise the image(with @2X) is for iPhone 6, iPhone 5 or iPhone 4?

Comment: How are you accessing the images?

Comment: For now i just using @2X and simple image name

Comment: No, I mean what code is used or how/where do you reference the images?

Comment: I just give the image name in my xib or story board file

Comment: My simple question is that , we use @2X for 1334x750 pixels, 1136x640 pixels, and 960x640 pixels resolutions then "How iOS will differ the image that where to place which image?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no publicly exposed way to differentiate your images between the various device sub-types.  If you must load a separate image depending upon whether your app is running on an iPhone 4s, 5, or 6, you will need to perform the detection of the device and loading of the proper image entirely in your own code (use the screen size to differentiate).

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that likewise `@3x` doesn't say anything about screen dimensions or aspect ratio, so you should also check screen size for iPhone 6 Plus if your needs have more to do with layout than scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

You may try **@3x**, though I haven't checked it.

Comment: @3x is only for iPhone 6 Plus